# Delete node of type Object from flex Tree component?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, tree, treeview

I have a tree with nodes, and a delete button, first user select the node and click this delete button, I want this node to be removed from the tree, Its not XML, every node in tree is of type Object
`{label:'folder',children:[{label:'file1'}]}`

I tried `delete myTree.selectedItem` (but compiler wont let me do it) 
also tried `myTree.selectedItem = nul`l (just unselects the item)
and also how can I access reference to parent object of myTree.selectedItem?

Comment: could you please add an example of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to remove leaf nodes with the MX Tree using the dataDescriptor.

```
var parent:Object = tree.getParentItem(tree.selectedItem);
var p:int = tree.itemRendererToIndex(tree.itemToItemRenderer(parent))   
var i:int = tree.itemRendererToIndex(tree.itemToItemRenderer(tree.selectedItem))    
tree.dataDescriptor.removeChildAt(parent,tree.selectedItem,i - p - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a parent node reference this is going to be quite hard. I would suggest to create a class TreeNode or so instead of a vanilla object. Besides the "label" and the "children" property, give the node a "parent" property and set the parent when you create the model for the tree.

Then when you select and item and click the remove button, you can get the parent node of the selected node and call a "removeChild" or so on it. This should then remove the given childnode.

It might be that you need to invalidate the model of tree after removing a node. You can do this with:

```
myTree.invalidateList();
```

Comment: I understand the first part but not the second , what for we need removeChild for ? instead of making changes to dataprovider ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var item:* = tree.selectedItem;
var parent:* = tree.getParentItem(item);

var p:int = tree.getItemIndex(parent);
var i:int = tree.getItemIndex(item);
var index:int = i - p - 1;

tree.dataDescriptor.removeChildAt(parent, item, index);
```

Almoust the same, but it works better for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this as your removal function:

```
private function removeEmployee():void {
 var node:XML = XML(tree.selectedItem);
 if( node == null ) return;       
 var children:XMLList = XMLList(node.parent()).children();
 for(var i:Number=0; i < children.length(); i++) {
   if( children[i].@name == node.@name ) {
       delete children[i];
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: casting object as xml wont work (in my case selectedItem is of type Object)